# Passing a string from html page to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, argument-passing

I have done a good amount of searching on how to pass data from a webpage to javascript but I have not found a solution to passing a string.  And that is exactly what I am trying to do, simply pass a string to a java script function.  The following is my code:

```
<a href = "website.html?gender='boy'">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/boy0023.png"/>
</a>

<a href = "website.html?gender='girl'">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:600px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/girl0023.png"/>
</a>
```

I have tried various ways to try and get this working including: removing the '' around boy and girl, using a button rather than a sprite, using "" around boy and girl.  So on click, I am redirected to the page and I create a global variable named gender to hold the information then try to use gender in my funciton as so:

```
var gender // Creates the global gender variable

init(gender){
    //code goes here
}
```

So I am not getting the results that I want on the page and when I go into console and type in gender; I receive the message that gender is undefined.  So my question is, what am I not understanding here and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you meaning to pass the variable back to the server? Or do you just want something to happen when the user clicks on the `<a>` link?

Comment: If you do want to just read the query string parameters in javascript after the page reloads, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Not one of those answers was helpful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Novocaine but AFAIK it's just matter of convention. I think The above will work in every browser. I'm just not sure about single quotes in Query strings

Comment: I am about to try these suggestions and I will let you guys know if it works out.  To clarify, I am wanting to click on one of the sprites (either the boy or girl image) and depending on the image that is clicked, I would like to load certain data based on that choice.  So if I am able to set gender to either 'boy' or 'girl' (which I have done manually in console) everything works fine after.  It is just setting it by using the webpage that is causing me trouble.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  I unfortunately wont be able to work on it more until later tonight.  I am pretty close using the get parameter by name function, I have just run into some issues that I didn't take into account.

Comment: @Nick If you no longer want an answer to this question, I think, you should delete it.

Comment: @akinuri I believe this question can serve others because it seems kind of unclear how strings should be handled.  Through the resources that others have posted, I have found a solution to my problem and will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regexp check on the url. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpx7epf2/1/)

```
// use window.location.href instead of string (the link)
var link = "website.html?gender=girl";
var gender;
if (link.indexOf("gender") != -1) {
    gender = link.match(/.*gender=(.*)/)[1];
}

/*
var gender;
if (window.location.href.indexOf("gender") != -1) {
    gender = window.location.href.match(/.*gender=(.*)/)[1];
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have it like calling a javascript function on 'onclick' of a tag rather than the href. And using window.location to change the page if needed. Refer to the fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/Lpx7epf2/5/

Code is as follows :- 
(HTML)

```
<a href="#" onclick="gender('boy')">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/boy0023.png"/></a>
<a href="#" onclick="gender('girl')">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:600px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/girl0023.png"/></a>
```

(JavaScript)

```
function gender(str){
    alert(str);//Use the value any way you want
    window.location="website.html?gender="+str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solved this issue:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var gender = getParameterByName('gender'); // Used as global variable

function init(gender) {
    gender = getParameterByName('gender'); //For some reason only works when it is reiterated localy
```